# VBS Confirm IE PopUp

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript, popup

I have the next HTML code:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContent$btn_update" value="Update" onclick="return confirm('You are about to update the data. Are you sure?');WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$MainContent$btn_update&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;Update_PL&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_MainContent_btn_update" class="normalButton" style="float: right; margin-right: 108px; margin-top: -3px; width: 130px; height: 50px; font-size: 24px;">
```

I have done a VB Script which take some actions in a web. The problem comes when I have to save these changes. To save them I've to click the button which code I posted above but, as you can see, it has an onclick event that throws an "Ok"/"Cancel" Pop-up.

I know how to click the button:

```
objIE.Document.getElementById("ctl00_MainContent_btn_update").Click()
```

but what I don't know how to do is to Click the "Ok" button shown below:

[image: IE Confirmation pop-up]

I have tried the next:

1. Use objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
2. Activate the IE pop-up window and use SendKeys

   objShell.AppActivate("Message from webpage")

   objShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
3. Activate the IE pop-up window with the name shown on Windows Task Manager - Applications. But the problem here is that the IE Web window and the IE pop-up window have the same name in the Windows Task Manager, so AppActivate doesn't know which one to activate.

** Using sendkeys I've tried SendKeys "{ENTER}" and SendKeys"%K" but no successful result.

The interesting part of the VBS code is:

```
For Each a In .document.getElementsByTagName("a")
                If InStr(a.GetAttribute("href"), linkToDetail)<> 0 And Not IsNull((InStr(a.GetAttribute("href"), linkToDetail))) Then
                    a.Click()
                    WaitWebLoad()
                    .document.getElementByID(editButton).Click()
                    WaitWebLoad()
                    .document.getElementByID(editArrivalDateTB).Value = activeSheet.Cells(rowIndex, columnArrivalDate).Value
                    .document.getElementByID(updateArrivalDateButton).Click()

                    'Something to press the OK button of the IE dialog window.

                    objShell.AppActivate(Window Title "- Internet Explorer")

                    WaitWebLoad()
                    objIE.document.getElementByID(backToSearchPL).Click()
                    WaitWebLoad()
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done!

As I was not able to click the OK button, I have deleted the code doing the pop-up to rise.

```
objIE.document.getElementById("nameOfTheButton").onclick = ""
objIe.document.getElementById("nameOfTheButton").Click()
```